# how to play specific track in background audio playback for windows phone 8?

Tags: audio, windows-phone-8

i need to create several buttons, and each of them will start playing different mp3 tracks on background audio playback template, the tutorial that i found only tells me how to go next track or previous track, not play specific track on a button click, pls help

this is the msdn tutorial link for background audio playback development
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202978(v=vs.105).aspx

tks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a solution from msdn:

You use the BackgroundAudioPlayer.Instance.Track property to change them.
once you set the track, wait for the track ready player state changed to play it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
            var stream = Application.GetResourceStream(<uri to file>);
            var effect = SoundEffect.FromStream(stream.Stream);
            var soundInstance = effect.CreateInstance();

            FrameworkDispatcher.Update();
            soundInstance.Play();
```

Comment: hi, tks for the reply. i'm new to the windows phone dev, i'm using background audio agent to play audios for now, your solution seems using another solution (soundeffect maybe?)

Comment: is it possible to use BackgroundAudioPlayer.Instance calls to play specific audio file? tks

Comment: This example uses XNA